# Working with the Covid Package from PyPi and I get the "object doesn't have this attribute" but Documentation says otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I as mentioned in the question, I am working with the covid package. I am building a simple covid tracking app with tkinter and I get the following error:

```
Label(main, text='Total active cases: ' + str(covid.get_total_active_cases())).grid(row=3, column=2)
AttributeError: 'Covid' object has no attribute 'get_total_active_cases'
```

This is intended to get the current active cases from the covid package. When I look at the documentation, it states that this is the proper example usage:

```
active = covid.get_total_active_cases()
```

Here is my Tkinter window program:

```
main = Tk()
main.geometry('400x300')
main.title('Covid19 Tracker')
Label(main, text='Corona Virus(COVID-19)', font='Helvetica 12 bold').grid(row=1, column=3)
Label(main, text='Total confirmed cases: ' + str(covid.get_total_confirmed_cases())).grid(row=2, column=2)
Label(main, text='Total active cases: ' + str(covid.get_total_active_cases())).grid(row=3, column=2)
Label(main, text='Total deaths: ' + str(covid.get_total_deaths())).grid(row=4, column=2)
Label(main, text='Total recoveries: ' + str(covid.get_total_recovered())).grid(row=5, column=2)
Button(main, text='Get individual status', command=indv).grid(row=6, column=3)
```

The odd part is that all of the other attributes are okay and functioning. As soon as I add this one, it no longer functions. Is this a coding error, Python error, Tkinter error, or neither of them? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide a [mre] and basically it is telling you that you can't use `covid.get_total_active_cases()`, it's that simple, if you want to use it you need to use `worldometers` as the source

Comment: @Matiiss What exactly do you mean by using worldometers as a source?  Here is the official PyPi Documentation for it. [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/covid/) I did everything correctly too.

Comment: you clearly missed the part where it switched from john hopkins to worldometers as the source

Comment: basically use `covid = Covid(source="worldometers")` and you should provide a [mre] when asking a question

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you! I didn't see that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter, since you can reproduce the problem without any tkinter code.